# Parsing paragraphs into separate documents in Solr using script

Tags: solr, nutch

I would like to crawl through a list of sites using Nutch, then break up each document into paragraphs and sending them to Solr for indexing.

I have been using the following script to automate the process of crawling/fetching/parsing/indexing:

```
bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/nutch -s ./urls/ Crawl 2
```

My idea is to attach a script in the middle of this workflow (probably the parsing stage of Nutch?) that would break up the paragraphs, like `paragraphs.split()`.  How could I accomplish this?

Additionally, I need to add a field to each paragraph that shows its numerical position in the document, and to what chapter it belongs to. The chapter is an h2 tag in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is not a very easy answer to your question. To accomplish this you need custom code, specifically, Nutch has two different plugins to deal with parsing HTML code `parse-html` and `parse-tika`. These plugins are focused on extracting text content and not so much structured data out of the HTML document.

You would need to have a custom parser (`HtmlParserPugin`) plugin that will treat paragraph nodes within your HTML document in a custom way (extracting the content and positional information).

The other component that you would need is for modeling the data in Solr, since you need to keep the position of the paragraph within the same document you also need to send this data in a way that it is searchable in Solr, perhaps using nested documents (this *really* depends on how you plan to use the data).

For instance, you may take a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/ATLANTBH/nutch-plugins/blob/master/nutch-plugins/filter-xpath) which implements custom logic for extracting data using arbitrary X Path expressions from the HTML.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for your answer, that clears up things. Maybe there's an opportunity to integrate this more fully into Nutch or Solr?

Comment: Sure! We always welcome new contributions! The tricky part (in my experience) is that almost everyone has different requirements either for the parsing (which elements to include) or for the storage format of the data which makes it a bit tricky to get right for everybody. The strength of Nutch, in these cases, is that it usually offers the right extension points for inserting your own custom logic.